# Prerequisities List, Corresponding list

Tags: java, collections

I'm working on a student registration system project (without a GUI).

I have the following entities: instructors, students, Course, ConsentRequest, Semester, Sections and Person

**Semester class**

```
package registrationsystem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Semester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>(5);
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>(5);
    ArrayList<Instructors> instructors = new ArrayList<Instructors>(5);
    ArrayList<Sections> sections = new ArrayList<Sections>(5);
    String [][] prerequisities={{"MIS132","MIS131"},{"TRM256","TRM201"}};
    String [][] corresponding={{"TRM256","MIS132"},{"TRM101","MIS131"}};



    double [][] CourseTaken=new double[20][20];
    double [][] InstructorSections=new double[20][20];

    Students s1=new Students("Ahmet");
    Students s2=new Students("Onur");
    Students s3=new Students("Veli");
    Students s4=new Students("Orhan");


    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);
    students.add(s4);



    Instructors i1=new Instructors("Jack","Dr");
    Instructors i2=new Instructors("Onur","Prof");
    Instructors i3=new Instructors("Veli","Dr");
    Instructors i4=new Instructors("Orhan","Prof");

    //HERE Course c1=new Course("IntroductiontoJavaProgramming",3,"MIS131",prerequisities[0][0],corresponding[0][0]); //*HERE
    Course c2=new Course("ObjectOriented",4,"MIS132");
    Course c3=new Course("CommunicationBasis",3,"TRM101");
    Course c4=new Course("BusinessCommunication",3,"TRM256");

    Sections se1=new Sections(15,i1,"MIS132.01",4,"MIS132");
    Sections se2=new Sections(20,i2,"MIS132.02",4,"MIS132");
    Sections se3=new Sections(16,i4,"TRM256.02",3,"TRM256");
    Sections se4=new Sections(19,i3,"MIS 131.01",3,"MIS131");
    Sections se5=new Sections(35,i4,"TRM101.01",3,"TRM101");




}
}
```

Each student takes a course, but there is an obligation that the student has to pass a prerequisite lesson before he can be allowed to take the course. Or he is required to take a corresponding course.

For example, if a student wants to take MIS132 lesson, first he has to take MIS131 lesson because it is the prerequisite course or a CMP15 lesson because it is corresponding lesson of MIS131.

So my question is that how can I put course class to a prerequisite list and a corresponding list and then in main class , i can call this method with parameters. I wrote 'HERE' in the code

**Courses.java**

```
package registrationsystem;
import java.util.*;
public class Course {

    private String name;
    private int credit;
    private String code;
    String[][] prerequisitelist = new String[5][5];
    String[][] correspondinglist=new String[5][5];


    protected Course(String name,int credit,String code,String[][] prerequisitelist,String[][] correspondinglist){
        this.name=name;
        this.credit=credit;
        this.code=code;
        this.prerequisitelist=prerequisitelist;
        this.correspondinglist=correspondinglist;

    }



}
```

Comment: 1: In your `Courses.java` class you don't need to make the lists into `new String[5][5]` when you declare them because you will be passing in arrays to the constructor. 2: Just pass the name of the variables (prerequisities, correspondinglist), because when you pass in `correspondinglist[0][0]` you are passing the `String` object at that location in the two-dimensional array, not the arrays. Your compiler would have told you what was wrong

Comment: but how can i set the proper matching between lessons and their prerequisities list if i only write prerequisities,correspondinglist as a parameter in the main class courses array?